# highlight unix code using jquery

Tags: jquery, unix, highlight

I try to color code written in Unix language, but I think that I neglect something ..? http://jsfiddle.net/QT9Fx/

```
$("body").load(function() {
sh_highlightDocument('lang/', '.lsm');
});
```

Thank's

Comment: You're not including the libraries you're relying on in your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the format "[Linux Software Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Software_Map)" (class `sh_lsm`) for highlighting but your text is a shell script. For this you can use the class `sh_sh`

And include the scripts as already suggested.

Here is your fiddle with working color codes http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/QT9Fx/7/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to include a few scripts:

```
<script src = "http://shjs.sourceforge.net/sh_main.js"></script>
<script src= "http://shjs.sourceforge.net/lang/sh_cpp.js"></script>
```

and one css file:

`<link href="http://shjs.sourceforge.net/sh_style.css"></link>`
. Also I tried with your code and doesn't work, not sure , I'm not linux expert, probably something is wrong with code. Here is example for cpp code: http://jsfiddle.net/QT9Fx/6/